# About $ \int_{(0,1)^n} \frac{1}{x_1^{\alpha_1}+x_2^{\alpha_2}+...+x_n^{\alpha_n}} dm_n $

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I'd like to prove the following two results, but besides the "trivial" implications, I haven't been able to crack them:

$$ \int_{(0,1)^n} \frac{1}{x_1^{\alpha_1}+x_2^{\alpha_2}+...+x_n^{\alpha_n}} dm_n < +\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\alpha_i} > 1$$
$$ \int_{(1,\infty)^n} \frac{1}{x_1^{\alpha_1}+x_2^{\alpha_2}+...+x_n^{\alpha_n}} dm_n < +\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\alpha_i} < 1$$

Answer (score 2):

I have supposed $\alpha_k>0$ for all $k$. For $x_1^{\alpha_1}+\cdots+x_n^{\alpha_n}>0$, you have:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-t(x_1^{\alpha_1}+\cdots+x_n^{\alpha_n}))dt=\frac{1}{x_1^{\alpha_1}+\cdots+x_n^{\alpha_n}}$$
Hence using Fubini

$$\int_{[0,1]^n}\frac{dm_n}{x_1^{\alpha_1}+\cdots+x_n^{\alpha_n}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n(\int_0^1\exp(-tx_k^{a_k})dx_k)dt$$

Now
$$\int_0^1\exp(-tx^{\alpha})dx=\frac{1}{\alpha t^{1/\alpha}}\int_0^t\exp(-u)u^{1/\alpha-1}du$$ Remark: For $t>0$ we have $$\frac{1}{\alpha t^{1/\alpha}}\int_0^t\exp(-u)u^{1/\alpha-1}du
\leq 1$$ 
And your integral is
$$\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_n}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n\int_0^t\exp(-x_k)x_k^{1/a_k-1}dx_k)}{t^{1/a_1+\cdots1/a_n}} dt$$

Now the convergence at $0$ is easy using the remark, and as the integrals $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty}\exp(-x_k)x_k^{1/a_k-1}dx_k$ are convergent, it easy to finish the proof of your first assertion. I suppose that there is a similar proof for the second assertion.